# Object Not Found in case_when within pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    gov1rlc gov2rlc gov3rlc gov1vote gov2vote gov3vote
    <int>   <int>   <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
    3       2      NA    24.35     1.04        0
    2       3       2      NA      24.35       1.04        
    3       2      NA    24.35     1.04        0
    3      NA      NA    54.40     0.00        0
    3      NA      NA    54.40     0.00        0
    3      NA      NA    54.40     0.00        0
```

At this point, I want to calculate the vote share of left-wing parties (gov1rlc, gov2rlc, gov3rlc equal 3), for that I use the following code:

```
d <- d %>% mutate(left_share=case_when(gov1rlc==3&gov2rlc==3&gov3rlc==3~gov1vote+gov2vote+gov3vote,
         gov1rlc==3&gov2rlc==3&gov3rlc!=3~gov1vote+gov2vote,
         gov1rlc==3&gov2rlc!=3&gov3rlc==3~gov1vote+gov3vote,
         gov1rlc==3&gov2rlc!=3&gov3rlc!=3~gov1vote,
     gov1rlc!=3&gov2rlc!=3&gov3rlc!=3~0,
     gov1rlc!=3&gov2rlc==3&gov3rlc==3~gov2vote+gov3vote,
     gov1rlc!=3&gov2rlc==3&gov3rlc!=3~gov2vote,
     gov1rlc!=3&gov2rlc!=3&gov3rlc==3~gov3vote))`
```

However, afterwards I get `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : object 'gov1rlc' not found`, which is really strange considering that I'm in a pipe, and the same code worked in another computer.

If i use the `d$` operator before every object, the following message is shown: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments`.

Putting it simply: what is happening and what is going on?

Comment: Sounds like you’re using a very old version of dplyr. An update should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is not a direct answer to your question of interest, but it appears you are trying to sum across columns in your data.frame. If we can assume that the NA values refer to right-share votes, it would be more flexible and simpler to maintain to sum using something like:

```
df %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(vote_share = sum(gov1vote, gov2vote, gov3vote, na.rm = T))
```

This should generate the same information as your current code, and it is within the tidyverse framework you are going for. I echo Konrad's comment that you update tidyverse to the most recent edition as well. I don't believe `rowwise()` was added until somewhat recently.

Comment: Thank you so much, Jacob and Konrad. An update of tidyverse completely solved the problem!